# how to obtain a regular expression for validation email address for one domain ONLY?

Tags: regex, swift, email-validation, nsregularexpression

I am struggling with writing a regex for validating email address for only one domain.

I have this expression

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}
```

But the issue is that for example `hello@gmail.com.net` is valid and I only want to be only valid for only one domain. So hence I do not want `hello@gmail.com.net` to be valid.

Help is needed. Thank you!

Comment: Please give more examples of what you want to match and what you want not to match.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If your question involves regular expressions name the "flavor" (i.e. the program you are using).

Comment: What do you mean by only one domain? You mean it should only work for `@gmail.com`, but not any other domain? Or do you mean domains with only one `.` in them?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I mean that it should work with other domains BUT with only one . (dot) in them. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Yunnosch It should work with all the domains, just that it must only include a . dot in them. Examples: h@g.com, h@h.net, h@g.global NOT h@g.com.global -> I hope you understand my point.

Comment: You mean a single dot? In that case I recommend the answer by fastr.de. Please edit your question to add the information from your comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch exactly, I mean a single dot. Yeah i looked over the answer of fastr.de, worked on it a bit and it works like a charm. The question is also edited.

Comment: Any particular reason why you would want to do this? Lots of legitimate email addresses are in nested domains. For instance, most addresses in the UK are `@something.co.uk` or `@something.ac.uk`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}`.
In your regex is a dot in the allowed characters behind the @.

Comment: I tried it like this and it works:

"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
\b[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@gmail\.com\.net\b
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxRmPq/1)

Comment: Check the info by OP in comments, I think you are off target.

Answer (score 0):

I found this regex for Swift:

`[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}`

It has an extra backslash.

I found it here: http://emailregex.com/

Regards,

Melle

Comment: Check info by OP in comments and test the examples given. I think you are off target.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accept an answer but this idea just cross my mind. You can use `URLComponents` to split the email address into `user` and `host` and validate each component separately:

```
func validate(emailAddress: String) -> Bool {
    guard let components = URLComponents(string: "mailto://" + emailAddress),
        let host = components.host else
    {
        return false
    }

    return host.components(separatedBy: ".").count == 2
}

print(validate(emailAddress: "hello@gmail.com"))        // true
print(validate(emailAddress: "hello@gmail.com.net"))    // false
print(validate(emailAddress: "hello"))                  // false
```

Your requirement has a big flaw in it though: valid domains can have two dots, like `someone@bbc.co.uk`. [Getting a regex pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to validate an email is hard. Gmail, for example, will direct all emails sent to `jsmith+abc@gmail.com` to the same inbox as `jsmith@gmail.com`. The best way is to perform some rudimentary check on the email address, then email the user and ask them to click a link to confirm the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below pattern.

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((REPLACE_THIS_WITH_EMAIL_DOMAIN+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

for Eg.

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((gmail+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```